# Access deep properties and methods using a string path in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a code snippet that I have been using and works. It is used a lot in my application and I need to speed it up. Is there a faster better way of deep accessing objects using as string path. It needs to able to access properties and methods, see my examples below:

```
     function get(obj, path) {
        var paths = path.split('.'),
        curProp = obj;
        for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
            if (!curProp[paths[i]]) return 
            curProp = (typeof curProp[paths[i]] !== "function") ? curProp[paths[i]] : curProp[paths[i]]() ;
        }
        return curProp;
    }
```

The snippet gets the property via the path for the object passed

```
var obj = {contact:{name:"john"}};
console.log(get("contact.name",obj));
```

If the object has a method that returns an object it can return that too

```
var obj = {contact:function(){return {name:"john"}}};
console.log(get("contact.name",obj));
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. Otherwise, please clarify the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming? Why are you making an exception for function *values*?

Answer (score 1):

The very nature of your question – ie, accessing deep properties programmatically – shows you're approaching functional programming with your own ideas of how it should work.

Functional-style programs will not use objects in this way. Even tho we can express your program in a functional style (below), whatever part of your program that uses the `get` function should probably be refactored not to use dynamic objects and dynamic object look-ups.

Similarly, using *methods* to store an object's values also comes from object-oriented style. Once you stop thinking about things in OO-style, you can begin to see the unique strengths of functional style.

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ tag: recur, values })

const loop = (f) =>
  {
    let acc = f ()
    while (acc && acc.tag === recur)
      acc = f (...acc.values)
    return acc
  }

const get = (obj = {}, path = []) =>
   loop ((o = obj, [p, ...ps] = path.split ('.')) =>
     (p === undefined)
       ? o
       : o[p] === undefined
         ? undefined
         : recur (o[p], ps))

const data =
  { a: { b: { c: 1, d: null } } }

console.log (get (data, 'a'))      // { b: { c: 1 } }
console.log (get (data, 'a.b'))    // { c: 1 }
console.log (get (data, 'a.b.c'))  // 1
console.log (get (data, 'a.b.c.')) // undefined
console.log (get (data, 'd'))      // undefined
console.log (get (data, 'a.b.d'))  // null
```

Comment: In your tests you don't return a method, in my code it returns properties and methods, {a:1,b:function(){return{c:1}}}

Comment: Why bother with functional-style if you're just going to bring your oo-style habits with you? Your question doesn't really make sense :(

Comment: Sorry if my question does not make sense all i want to do is discuss if my code can be optimized to return the results shown?

Comment: The example data is not how the function is used. For sure the function needs to be able to walk through methods to get to new properties. Most javascript libraries use objects (classes) that return properties and methods. I just need a means to access them using a string path? Is that bad design?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the entire program of course, but in my opinion, using dynamic properties on objects is a bad design – When you have objects that guarantee *known* (static) properties, it affords you all sorts of conveniences in your code. With dynamic properties, you can never be sure any such property is set, nor can you know what type that property would be, so you have to do all sorts of safety checks in other parts of your program. It's a nightmare of your own invention. Some oo-style idioms can be adapted to a functional-style "equivalent"; some can't.

Comment: It's not being used for dynamic properties perhaps my example data was badly thought through. I may have object person that has attached an object address person will have a property name, i need and address will have a property street. I need to be able to walk through to street from a string path. I don't know if that is bad design but most libraries follow a similar pattern?

Comment: @MartinWebb people, even successful bloggers/library authors, frequently commit code atrocities simply because they don't know any better (for evidence, I offer up every PHP tutorial in the history of ever). Sometimes they do it because they have an ambitious goal and the only way to make it work/perform fast enough/handle an edge case in a browser you've never heard of/etc. is to hack it. Only the burned have a healthy respect for (or crippling fear of) playing with fire. The question is not 'can I do this thing' but 'is this worth the tradeoff'? Choose wisely, with care.

Comment: (...cont) to put it another way, ever looked at any of Google's JavaScript code? It's *terrible*. It's full of verbose ugly patterns, weird and seemingly unneeded indirection, etc. Why? Because their code has to run in everything from web browsers built into game consoles and toasters to their own desktop chrome consistently and fast. Most of us, even most of us making customer-facing software, don't occupy that world. We should optimize for brevity, maintainability, reliability, etc. We have license to use the stuff (like FP) they *wish* they could use, and should.

Comment: happy new year, Jared ^_^